# Parametrization of polygons and polyhedra

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

So, I've got a pretty interesting problem:

I was wondering how one would go about trying to generate every n-gon, or at least parametrize the space of a specific n-gon (say a hexagon) so it's easily spanned.

For instance, what are the best variables to define an n-gon such that one could easily cycle through them with a loop.

And then, how would one do this with polyhedra? One constraint is that all the shapes should have the same area/volume.

For some perspective, I'm currently running some physics computations that take in polyhedral meshes and output physical characteristics for each mesh, and we need to have a good way of cycling through the shapes.

Answer (score 4):

One route, perhaps not appropriate for your application because
of the area constraint (see end of this post), is to fix a set $S$ of $n$ points in the plane, and then walk among all the (in general exponentially many) different *[simple polygonalizations](http://erikdemaine.org/polygonization/)* $P$ of $S$. I coauthored one paper on this myself:

> Damian, Mirela, Robin Flatland, Joseph O’Rourke, and Suneeta Ramaswami. "Connecting polygonizations via stretches and twangs." *Theory of Computing Systems* 47, no. 3 (2010): 674-695.
>   ([Pre-journal arXiv abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1942).)

---

[image: TwangsFig6]

---

More generally,
a nice (but now out-of-date) web page on generating *random polygons* was
maintained by Jeff Erickson [here](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/open/randompoly.html).

There is less work on polyhedralizations of fixed point sets, or random (not necessarily convex) polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Here is one reference:

> Agarwal, Pankaj K., Ferran Hurtado, Godfried T. Toussaint, and Joan Trias. "On polyhedra induced by point sets in space." *Discrete Applied Mathematics* 156, no. 1 (2008): 42-54. ([PDF download pre-journal version](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/bbdlink.pdf).)

If generating random *convex* polyhedra suffices for your purposes, there are many approaches. See, e.g.,

> Schneider, Rolf. "Recent results on random polytopes." *Boll. Unione Mat. Ital.*(9) 1.1 (2008): 17-39. ([PDF download pre-journal version](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/rschnei/Vortrag.Perugia.pdf).)

I think achieving your constant area/volume constraint will be challenging. For example, finding a polygonization of minimum area of a fixed point set
is NP-hard.